# Android: Updating single item in ListView without freezing the others

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, notifydatasetchanged

I have a ListView with items that are updated asynchronously(either their content is changed or the item is removed altogether). To do so I update the dataset for the adapter of the ListView and then I call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the adapter. This works well, however each item has a `ProgressBar` (spinning), that indicates that the item has not been updated yet. When an update arrives for one of the items and `notifyDatasetChanged()` is called the `ProgressBar`s of the other items freeze for a moment, which seems like a bad user experience. Also I use the `ViewHolder` pattern in my adapter.

Is there a way I could update just one item of the ListView, without freezing all the others?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) - it has a big variety of notify...()  methods.

Have a look at [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) - I think you can use it.

You can simply make something like that :

```
mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(itemChangedIndex);
```

Comment: It seems like this could work. I will try it and post back with the results.

Comment: Was unaware of this. Great answer!